# Is a two and half year degree valid for New Zealand Work Permit

Tags: working-visas, immigration, education, new-zealand, brazilian-citizens

I received a job offer from New Zealand. I have a degree well recognized in my country as a tertiary education. However it is not a bachelor's Degree.

It is a Diploma, usually called Associate Degree.

Is this diploma valid for me to immigrate as a Skilled Worker?

Thanks.

Comment: What country are you from?

Comment: Do you have a few years of professional work experience in your field? If you do, that may count toward making up the difference between an Associate and a Bachelor degree.

Comment: I From Brazil, and I have more than 5 years of experience as Software Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Your Associate Degree is probably considered level 5 or 6 in the [NZQF](http://glossary.immigration.govt.nz/NZRegisterOfQualityAssuredQualifications.htm). This counts for a certain number of points in the points-based assessment system of the Skilled Migrant category. A Bachelor's Degree would probably count for 10 more points. Years of work experience in your area of expertise also counts for points. From [Can I apply under the Skilled Migrant Category](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/skilledmigrant/caniapply/):

> Recognised qualification: We award 40-60 points for a variety of trade certificates, diplomas, bachelors degrees and post-graduate qualifications. You can get bonus points for qualifications, too.

If you haven't already, you should visit the [Skilled Migrant Category Points Indicator](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/pointsindicator/) to see how many points you might be eligible for. From what I guessed about your situation, you should be able to get at least 150 points easily (100 is the minimum required to submit an Expression of Interest).

An actual job offer looks like it's worth perhaps 70 points itself, which is most of the points you need anyway.